# Call overridden method of Activity from other class

Tags: java, android, polymorphism

Hi I have an `Interface` and an `Activity`.

My Activity implements that Interface and have overrided the method of Interface.

now I have to call that overridden method of Interface from another Class so that overridden method of Activity gets executed.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: nothing different same as call method of activity from another class

Answer (score 2):

I am able to call overridden method of Activity from other class as

```
 ((name of Interface) context).documentRead(dataUnit);
```

Answer (score 0):

just share the reference of the **activity implementing the interface as the object of interface** and then simply **call the overridden method on that reference**. Basic OOP concept.